# Customizing the article attachment in the send an email functionality

Tags: attachment, pdf, articles, send-email

As per standard salesforce functionality, while using Send an Email from a case, you have the option to attach the article as an attachment to the email that is sent.

Salesforce has a certain formatting style for these articles and we don't want this standard formatting. I have a requirement where these article PDFs that are attached and sent in the email are to be formatted in a certain style.

Is there any way of doing this. Has anyone worked on anything similar to this.